# Union of deletion Cantor sets

Tags: lebesgue-measure, fractals, cantor-set

I know that it is possible to have deletion Cantor set which are of non-zero measure (fat Cantor sets) furthermore it must never of measure one since it would result in a contradiction (as Cantor is nowhere dense but full measure implies dense in $[0,1]$).

I have found that there exists a partition of $[0,1]$ by Cantor sets. Now if it is countable (not necessarily finite) it holds that the Lebesgue measure of the union is the sum of the measure of each set.

My question is; can we construct such union with fat Cantor sets and such that it is countable?

If so, can we "add" enough such disjoint fat Cantor sets so that the measure of the union is one (i.e. the union has full measure in $[0,1]$)?

Any help is appriciated!

Comment: What is a "deletion Cantor set"? I've never heard that term before.

Comment: @bof A deletion cantor set is in some sense the generalisation of what the Cantor Middle thirds set is. Let me be more precise, it is any set which is constructed iteratively by removing open intervals from the unit interval [0,1] such that the set $D_{n}$ at the $n^{th}$ iteration is the union of $2^{n}$ closed, disjoint subintervals each of positive lenght.

Comment: So a deletion Cantor set is not necessarily nowhere dense, it could coutain intervals; e.g. the deleted open intervals could all be contained in the interval $[0.7,0.8]$.

Comment: @bof I believe it is necessarily nowhere dense, since all such deletion cantor sets are homeomorphic and dense sets are preserved under homeomorphisms (but I might be wrong here)

Comment: @bof sorry that is right it also has to satisfy that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $n \geq 1$ such that $|D_{n,i}|\leq \epsilon$ for when $1\leq i \leq 2^{n}$  where $n$ is the number of the step in the iterative construction we are at and $i$ is the number of the interval we are at (counting from left to right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would violate Baire Category Theorem. So we need uncountable many fat Cantor sets to cover $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was looking for. More specifically is it correct to say that it contradicts "(BCT3) A non-empty complete metric space with nonempty interior, or any of its subsets with nonempty interior, is not the countable union of nowhere-dense sets. " since $[0,1]$ is trivially nonempty and has nonempty interior (since $(0,1)$ is its interior) hence BCT3 applies. We know a partition of $[0,1]$ by nowhere dense sets exists and BCT3 tell us it cannot be countable.